# Highlighting user entered text in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I use Lucene to do completely full-text searches, ie. when user enters search string "abc" I automatically append wildcards and search for "abc*" or "`*abc*`" (depending on field). For istance, the queries look, more or less, like this:

```
field1:abc* field2:*abc* field3:*abc*
```

Now, I would like to highlight, in search ourput, **only** character strings entered by the user (not the entire terms that match the wildcards). For instance, for the aforemoentioned "abc" search string, I would like to have such hightlights:

**abc**d**abc**d lorem ipsum

lorem ipsum **abc**

**abc**xyz lorem ipsum

lorem ipsum xyq**abc**

The example of using Lucene Highligher ( http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/api/contrib-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/package-summary.html ) works fine with highlighting whole terms, but is there any (easy) way to only highlight user entered text?